# assertion dict with regex

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

Its possible assert dict with regex ?

example: dict

```
{
    "mimetype": "application/json",
    "status_code": 200,
    "data": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "foo",
      "access_token": "5151818748748"
  }
}
```

with: regex in key `access_token`

```
{
    "mimetype": "application/json",
    "status_code": 200,
    "data": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "foo",
      "access_token": "(.+)"
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Is this part of a web framework or something? Where is the regex assertion supposed to take place? You need to give us some context here. Assume that we are not sitting right next to you right now....

Comment: @tdelaney i using it in unittest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly:

```
import re

def assert_dict(template, thing):
    if len(template) != len(thing):
        raise AssertionError("Assertion failed")
    for key in template:
        if isinstance(template[key], dict):
            assert_dict(template[key], thing[key])
        else:
            if template[key] == thing[key]:
                continue
            elif re.fullmatch(template[key], thing[key]):
                continue
            else:
                raise AssertionError("Assertion failed")
```

This checks if they have the same key-value pairs, and if so, first tests whether they are the same, and if not, whether the second matches the first.

This will work as long as there's nothing fancy inside the dictionaries. Lists will work, but not dicts in lists, although it would be fairly trivial to implement that, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue:

```
expected = {'test_res': 'Correct', ..lots more.., 'query_date': '2023-05-10T10:15:48'}
actual =  {'test_res': 'Correct', ..lots more.., 'query_date': '2023-05-12T11:51:34'}
```

Obviously the actual data is going to differ from your original 'expected' data, so why not do this.

```
actual['query_date'] = expected['query_date']
```

It's obviously not a regex match, so you can't check formats, but it does cater for values that are always going to differ (and you don't care about) when the test is run.

Then you can do:

```
assertDictEquals(expected,actual)
```

... and the test will pass

If you did want to check the excluded field(s) then you could always check these separately using assertRegex. e.g.

```
assertRegexMatches(actual['query_date'], '^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[0')
```

(this is not actual regex to match date!)